# Module does not exist error in Brackets.io extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-brackets

I'm developing an extension for Brackets.io editor. I want to load `trie-search`, an `npm` module.

I `cd`ed to the local directory of the extension then run:

```
npm install trie-search
```

The extension code has to look like this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var AppInit           = brackets.getModule("utils/AppInit"),
        CodeHintManager     = brackets.getModule("editor/CodeHintManager"),
        LanguageManager     = brackets.getModule("language/LanguageManager" ),
        TrieSearch          = require('trie-search'), // throws an error
        MGfuncHint          = require('text!mg-func.txt');
```

This throws an error saying `module does not exist`. How could I load the module?

Answer (score 0):

U may want to try the below.

```
var TrieSearch = new NodeDomain("simple", ExtensionUtils.getModulePath(module, "trie-search"));
```

Reference link:
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Node-Process:-Overview-for-Developers#usage-example

Hope it helps

Cheers